# Ogre on OSX with Xcode 4.3.2 pbxcp error

Tags: ogre, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When building ogre with Xcode 4.3 (and probably higher), one may run into this erorr message:
/bin/sh: /Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp: Not a directory

The reason is that Xcode does not install tools in /Developer anymore. The tools are now available at  /Application/Xcode.app. But ogre 1.7 has hardcoded the path to pbxcp in the CMakefiles.

Workaround:
Add one line in  visualization_common/ogre/Makefile, which patches the ogre CMakeLists.txt

```
installed_osx: $(SOURCE_DIR)/unpacked
    # Replace @executable_path/../... with @rpath/
    find $(SOURCE_DIR) -name CMakeLists.txt -exec sed -i bak s:executable_path/../Frameworks:rpath/: {} \;
    find $(SOURCE_DIR) -name CMakeLists.txt -exec sed -i bak s:executable_path/../Components:rpath/: {} \;
    find $(SOURCE_DIR) -name CMakeLists.txt -exec sed -i bak s:executable_path/../Plugins:rpath/: {} \; 
+   find $(SOURCE_DIR) -name CMakeLists.txt -exec sed -i bak s:/Developer/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/pbxcp:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents//OtherFrameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Versions/A/Resources/pbxcp: {} \;
    mkdir -p $(SOURCE_DIR)/build
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32516/ogre-on-osx--with-xcode-4.3.2-pbxcp-error/) by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 91 on 2012-04-24

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another way is to switch from pbxcp to ditto see https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/browser/stacks/visualization_common/trunk/ogre/ditto_pbxcp_osx.patch?rev=39177

---

Originally posted by [tingfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/241/tingfan/) with karma: 91 on 2012-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1